# Rebol runtime window control create and update

Tags: ide, rebol

In the video : [REBOL VID demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAy9tBHiLJo) - Nenad Rakocevic demonstrates what seems the basic code to compose a Rebol IDE at runtime.

Can someone provide a working Rebol example on how to create, update / modify  faces (widget / control) within a View (window) at runtime.

So far the examples I found allow creating faces into a new window rather than update an existing one.

Thanks

Comment: The source of RealTime VID demo video of Nenad Rakocevic: [http://softinnov.org/dl/VID-Livecoding.zip](http://softinnov.org/dl/VID-Livecoding.zip).

Answer (score 4):

The secret is to use "show" after changing what you want to change. And experiment a lot. There are nice scripts on rebol.org that use VID.

If you meant the interactive nature of the demo, that is (23.34) only 30 lines of 'cod'. I have tried to find that 'cod' but could not find it.

Good luck!

Arnold

Comment: *I have tried to find that 'cod' but could not find it.*  That's because [these guys](http://www.massbayguides.com/Images/Cod%20Fishing%202011oho.jpg) ran off with them.  (You have to be careful when you license your cod.)

Comment: Thanks Arnold,

From what I gather from the video, Nenad is pushing the face changes through a socket.

Comment: I tried the `view/new` route, but event processing seem to need additional code.

Answer (score 3):

Terse example on how to update a face :

```
rebol[]

view layout [
    bx: box teal
    btn "ShowTime" [
        bx/text: now/time
        bx/color: random white
        show bx
    ]
]
```

Comment: Looks like you're over the 20 points now... so just a note [that gives you permission to join the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red) ... (it's more informal)